# How do I fix: AAPT: error: '@dimens/card_corner_radius' is incompatible with attribute cardCornerRadius (attr) dimension [weak]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, androidx

The dimension is incompatible with the attribute, I don't know why

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_margin="@dimens/card_margin"
     android:layout_marginLeft="@dimens/card_margin"
     android:layout_marginTop="@dimens/card_margin"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimens/card_margin"
     android:layout_marginBottom="@dimens/card_margin"

     app:cardCornerRadius="@dimens/card_corner_radius"
     app:cardElevation="2dp">

     <include layout="@layout/card_contents_1" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another namespace:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

...

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimens/card_corner_radius"
```

whatever `@dimens/card_corner_radius` may be.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/cardview/widget/CardView#attr_CardView_cardCornerRadius

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
```

instead of

```
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimens/card_corner_radius"
```